# How to float all the list items of navbar to right?

Tags: html, css

I want to put all the elements to right. How can I do it?[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASCnX.png)
[Here is my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOeSR.png)
I want all the items in ul to be at left of navbar as like in the figure.

I am expecting the list items to right or left how can I do it.
the float is not working for some reason am I making some mistakes or anything someone help me.

```css
nav {
  padding: 40px 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0vh 15vh;
}

li {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  nav {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  li {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Courses</li>
    <li>Forum</li>
    <li>Learning Paths</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: hello, display or float on li has no effect if ul is a flex or grid parent. Aside, float:left is not float:right ;) . so, on your media querie choose either flex,felx-end/end or just float:right for lis

Answer (score 2):

Set `justify-content: flex-end` on the list:

```css
nav {
  padding: 40px 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0vh 15vh;
}

li {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  nav {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  li {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Courses</li>
    <li>Forum</li>
    <li>Learning Paths</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: As a minor suggestion, `flex-end` can be replaced with just `end` for the same result (the `flex`prefix appears to have been removed, though browsers will treat the older syntax as an alias of the newer.).

Comment: As a side note, float or display has no effect on a direct flex(or grid)  child . it is being part of the grid and stands as a cell of that grid ;) .

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
   }
```

I think this is what u want to do, u doesn't need to use float( btw u cant use float when using dipslay:flex)
Without padding items will be on flex end as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To move all the list items to the right, you can add the CSS property justify-content: flex-end; to the ul element. This will align all the items to the right of the navbar. Here's the updated CSS:

```css
 nav{
   padding: 40px 50px;
   background-color: black;
 }
 ul{
   list-style-type:none;
   padding: 0vh 15vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
 }

 li{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0px 20px ;
 }

 @media screen and (min-width:768px) {
   nav{
      padding: 20px 20px;
      height: 30px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Courses</li>
    <li>Forum</li>
    <li>Learning Paths</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```